# Open source library to create collage of images in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have an UI like this,
http://ichris.ws/files/collage-picasa.jpg (Taken from google image search)

Where all the collage items are layouts overlapping each other in random orders and clickable.

Few things which I know is to use relative or frame layout to overlap the image layouts.
But is there any kind of open source library(custom views) which can achieve this ?
May be collage with tilted layouts too.

Comment: Did u find a way of achieving this?

Comment: Did u find a way of achieving this?

Comment: try this library...: https://github.com/jcmore2/Collage